# Retrieving data from MongoDB database with certain data range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, express, database

In nodeJS I am retrieving data from a mongoDB database. It works for all other cases (`{"name": 'user1'}` as find critera), expect when specifying a date range for which I would like to receive data for.

```
var collection = db.collection('collectionName');
collection.find(
      { "date": { $gte: new Date("2010-12-01"), $lt: new Date("2010-12-10")} }

,
 {}, (function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
         console.log(err);
     } else if (result.length) {
         console.log(result);
     } 
 }));
```

It must be noted that date data includes a timestamp date which was inserted using `new Date()` function

Document Stored in Collections:

```
[ { _id: 5849d924da9a361b503e8945,
name: 'user2',
date: 'Mon Dec 08 2010 22:05:23 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)'
 },
{ _id: 5849dabb2a9fdc2310d37c0e,
name: 'user1',
date: 'Thu Dec 01 2010 20:12:11 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)'
 } ]
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample docs to the post for which you are expecting results ?

Comment: The code looks good. is the date an actual date format in the schema?
also you might have to alter the date format. you could try `12/01/2012` for example

Comment: There is no defined schema for this collection. Basically, a timestamp has been pushed using `new Date()`